# How to make a hot deployment of a shared library in Weblogic?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic-10.x

My application AdfWeb.war is deployed at Weblogic 10.3.6.0. It is using one shared library my.shared.lib.jar which is modified very often. The server is running in a development mode.

Every time when I try to deploy new version of the library using option "Deploy to Application Server", I am getting the following error:

> [05:43:49 PM] [Deployer:149034] An exception occurred for task
>   [Deployer:149117] deploy library my.shared.lib
>   [LibSpecVersion=7.1.0,LibImplVersion=1.0.0] on ADFServer.: Cannot
>   undeploy library Extension-Name: my.shared.lib, Specification-Version:
>   7.1, Implementation-Version: 1.0.0 from server ADFServer, because the 
>   following deployed applications reference it: AdfWeb.war.
>   [05:43:49 PM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  #### 
>   [05:43:49 PM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)

The application is based on ADF. I am using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.
How to make a hot deployment of a shared library in Weblogic? Now I always have to stop an application, which takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a Hot Re-Deployment of a Shared Library which is being used by an application without restarting the application or the server.

I thought this guy was getting to it by playing with the library versions (this might interest you):

http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2010/07/redeploy-and-version-adf-shared.html

> There are already two versions of our ADF shared library deployed.
>   Because main site doesn't specify, which version of shared library to
>   use, the latest one will be always used automatically.
>
> Because we are using shared library deployment, there is no need to
>   redeploy main site

But then at the end he confirms what i said:

> We need to reload main site in order to use latest available shared
>   library. Otherwise we would need to restart WLS server in order to
>   pick up latest redamurai.shared.lib library updates

Class Loading...